# Why script will sometimes launch ExtendScript Toolkit & just stall

Tags: javascript, regex, macos, adobe-illustrator

Any ideas why sometimes when the script is called to run it will launch ExtendScript Toolkit & just stall? I think it maybe when there is a lot of text to go through. Not sure that is the case every time. See Pic below script.

If it stops it stops on the line:   var new_string = this_text_frame.contents.replace(search_string, replace_string);

```
    // Version 3

function myReplace(search_string, replace_string) {
    var active_doc = app.activeDocument;
    var text_frames = active_doc.textFrames;
    if (text_frames.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < text_frames.length; i++)
        {
            var this_text_frame = text_frames[i];
            var new_string = this_text_frame.contents.replace(search_string, replace_string);
            if (new_string != this_text_frame.contents)
            {
                this_text_frame.contents = new_string;
                }
            }
        }
    }
myReplace(/^PRG.*/i, "");
myReplace(/.*EBOM.*/i, "");
myReplace(/^PH.*0000.*/i, "");
myReplace(/^PH.*00\/.*/i, "");
//  N or W  &  6 #'s   &   -S_    EX. N123456-S_  REPLACE with:  N123456-S???    (THIS NEEDS TO BE ABOVE  _ REPLACED BY SPACE)
myReplace(/([NW]\d{6}-S)_/i, "$1??? ");

myReplace(/_/gi, " ");
//  6 #'s   &  - or no -  &  7 #'s   &  1 to 3 #'s   &  -    EX: 123456-1234567/123-  REPLACE with:  -123456-
myReplace(/(\d{6})-?\d{7}\/\d\d?\d?-/i, "-$1-");
myReplace(/(\d{6})-?\d{7}-\/\d\d?\d?-/i, "-$1-");

myReplace(/([NW]\d{6}-S)-INS-\d\d\/\d\d?-/i, "$1??? ");

myReplace(/-INS-\d\d\/\d\d?-/i, "* ");

//  -  That is only followed by one more -  &   Not having PIA   &  -  &   2 to 3 #'s   &   /   &   1 to 3 #'s   &   -      EX:   -7NPSJ_RH-001/9-   REPLACE with  * & Space
myReplace(/-[^-]*-\d\d\d?\/\d\d?\d?-/i, "* ");

myReplace(/ ?ASSEMBLY/gi, " ASY");
myReplace(/ ASS?Y+$| ASS?Y - | ASS?Y -| ASS?Y | ASS?Y- | ASS?Y-/gi, " ASY - ");

myReplace(/(MCA-|DS-?C1-?)/i, "-");

myReplace(/^DS-|^DI-|^PH-|MCA|^PAF-|^PAF|^FDR-|^FDR/i, "");

myReplace(/VIEW ([a-z])/i, "TTEMPP $1");

myReplace(/ ?\(?V?I?EW\)| ?\(?VIE[W)]?|^W\)| ?\(VI+$|^ ?\(VI| ?\(V+$|^ ?\(V| ?\(+$|^ ?\)/i, "");

myReplace(/TTEMPP ([a-z])/i, "VIEW $1");

myReplace(/([NW]\d{6}-S)-/i, "$1??? ");
myReplace(/([NW]\d{6}-S)\/.-/i, "$1??? ");

//   Needs to be in this order
myReplace(/ AND /i, "&");
myReplace(/WASHER/i, "WSHR");
myReplace(/BOLT/i, "BLT");
myReplace(/STUD/i, "STU");
myReplace(/([SCREW|SC|NUT|BLT|STU])&WSHR/i, "$1 & WSHR");
myReplace(/\?\?\? SCREW &/i, "??? SC &");
myReplace(/\?\?\? SC [^&]/i, "??? SCREW ");
myReplace(/(\?\?\? SC & WSHR).*/i, "$1");
myReplace(/(\?\?\? SCREW).*/i, "$1");
myReplace(/(\?\?\? NUT & WSHR).*/i, "$1");
myReplace(/\?\?\? NUT [^&].*/i, "??? NUT");
myReplace(/(\?\?\? BLT & WSHR).*/i, "$1");
myReplace(/\?\?\? BLT [^&].*/i, "??? BLT");
myReplace(/(\?\?\? STU & WSHR).*/i, "$1");
myReplace(/\?\?\? STU [^&].*/i, "??? STU");

myReplace(/--/gi, "-");


if ( app.documents.length > 0 && app.activeDocument.textFrames.length > 0 ) {
// Set the value of the word to look for
searchWord1 = "*";
//searchWord2 = "The";

// Iterate through all words in the document
// the words that match searchWord
for ( i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.textFrames.length; i++ ) {
textArt = activeDocument.textFrames[i];
for ( j = 0; j < textArt.characters.length; j++) {
word = textArt.characters[j];
if ( word.contents == searchWord1 ) {

word.verticalScale = 120;
word.horizontalScale = 140;
word.baselineShift = -3;
}
}
}
}
```

[img]http://i.imgur.com/9IRy9.jpg[/img]

This javascript is call to run from a applescript.

```
    set Apps_Folder to (path to applications folder as text)
set Scripts_Path to "Adobe Illustrator CS5:Presets.localized:en_US:Scripts:"
set JS_FileName to "Text Find & Replace.jsx"
--
try
    set JS_File to Apps_Folder & Scripts_Path & JS_FileName as alias
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
        do javascript JS_File show debugger on runtime error
    end tell
on error
    display dialog "Script file '" & JS_FileName & "' NOT found?" giving up after 2
end try
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you search for your Errorcode?

```
1346458189 ('MRAP')
```

It is at the bottom of the ESTK. have a look here http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/cs6/Readme.txt

Its not "MRAP", its "PARM" but the number fits.

> "An Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 ('PARM')" alert (1459349)
>   Affects: JavaScript
>    Problem:
>      This alert may appear when carelessly written scripts are repeatedly
>      run in Illustrator from the ExtendScript Toolkit.
>
> Each script run is executed within the same persistent ExtendScript
>      engine within Illustrator. The net effect is that the state of
>      the ExtendScript engine is cumulative across all scripts that
>      ran previously.
>
> The following issues with script code can cause this problem:
>
> - Reading uninitialized variables.
> - Global namespace conflicts, as when two globals from different
>      scripts have the same name.

In your script are some uninitialized variables

```
searchWord1 = "*"; 

textArt = activeDocument.textFrames[i];

word = textArt.characters[j];
```

Comment: I tried this http://pastebin.com/sNyNSB1h but it is not working.  Is this on the right track & close to a solution?

Comment: No. Sorry this is even worse. ;(  have a look at  this.https://gist.github.com/4351305 But this only looks for the characters content. Your searchTerms in the first script are RegExp syntax. So you have to use String.search or String.replace with them http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: This is very helpful, THANKS, I will work with it & try to learn more scripting I HOPE YOU HAVE A GOOD CHRISTMAS & NEW YEAR!

Comment: This answer helped me. I had some loose functions and that sort of thing, and wrapping everything in an anonymous self-executing function fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Its not "MRAP", its "PARM" but the number fits.

actually, on MacOS "MRAP" is the correct sentence returned. "PARM" is for windows.

My experience with this error :

I run a 2 000 lines' javascript.

I have to check for 700 folders contained each between 1 - 15 differents .ai files.

- on MACOS 10.7, I got this error 2 times for 15 folders, never the same file. (CS6)
- on Win8 I got this error 1 time for 5 folders, never the same file. (CC 2014)
- on win7 I got this error 1 time for 100 folders, never the same file. (CC 2014 or CS6)
- and finally I run it on a just installed win7 and I got no error, the script was running 10 hours without interruption. (CC 2014 or CS 6)

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure @fabianmoronzirfas has the technically correct and most likely answer, my recent experience with error `1346458189` is that is appears to be Illustrator's equivalent of Microsoft's infamous "Unknown error."  That is, it appears to be the catch-all error for anything Adobe didn't write a more informative error trap for.

For me, this unhelpful error was a result of trying to set the artboard too small (below 1 point).  Clearly, Illustrator doesn't do enough bounds checking.  For others, as far as I could tell from searching the net, it comes from a smattering of reasons.  Including, possibly, memory and other errors from within Illustrator's script processor, which would be one way to account for it's randomness in some scenarios.  Most likely, however, I suspect it is usually something solvable with more durable code.